# Oracle matching file extensions

Tags: regex, oracle

How can can I match String like this in Oracle:

```
73c49987f5378438a0d720e06e88338e/009-1216543_14_file1.xls 

74135a8a8b4831888859ab3e7fe1c728/009_0108571_15_file2.pdf

750182f2c19767b30149c511d334b097/file3.pdf
```

I came up with this:

```
Regexp_Like (mytext, '\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$','i')
```

But this catches only the strings like for example

```
'.xls'
```

but not

```
'73c49987f5378438a0d720e06e88338e/009-1216543_14_file1.xls'
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what your expected input/outputs are? Im not sure what you do and dont want to match

Comment: `Regexp_Like (mytext, '^.*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$','i')` - like this?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg: at least, let' say 20 characters like this '5d560dd67e22d9546263d' + '/' + variable number of characters, ending with '.' + 3 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
^.*\/.*\.[a-zA-Z]{3}$
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/rS7uL7/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one,

```
\w+\/(\d+-?_?)*\w+\.\w+{3}
```

[Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZ8iU1/2)

Comment: Close, but the string must end with a dot and three characters